# Error: Class Magneto_PopupQuestion\Products does not exist

Tags: magento2

hello I want to call the file in form.xml to display the product name but i am getting error class not found

form.xml

```
    <field name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">product name</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magneto_PopupQuestion\Products</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

products.php

```
<?php
namespace Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Products extends Column 
{
    protected $_ProductRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $ProductRepository,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_ProductRepository = $ProductRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as $key => $items) {
                $product = $this->_ProductRepository->getById($items["entity_id"]);
                $dataSource['data']['items'][$key]['entity_id'] = $product->getName(); //to get product name
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products</item>

Comment: Class Magento\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products does not exist is coming

Answer (score 0):

`Magneto_PopupQuestion\Products` is not a valid classpath

- Typo in Magento
- not the classes namespace

```xml
<item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products</item>
```

Comment: same error is coming Class Magento\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products does not exist

Comment: did you correct the namespace in your PHP-file?

Comment: yes no error but product name is not displaying i want to display product name through product id

Answer (score 0):

Use Full Class path:
`<item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products</item>`

Also verify either you are using **Magento** or **Magneto**.

```
<?php
namespace Magento\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column

use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Products extends Column 
{
    protected $_ProductRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $ProductRepository,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_ProductRepository = $ProductRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $product = $this->_ProductRepository->getById($item["entity_id"]);
                 $item[$fieldName] = $product->getName();
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Class Magento\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products does not exist is coming

Comment: Then you should write  `Magento\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products` in class argument you passed in item. also namespace in your Products.php file has typo,

Comment: no error is coming but the output does not come I want to display the product name through product id i have store product id

Comment: Check my updated code

Comment: what changes you have done i cannot see any change

Comment: i have changed code in prepareDataSource function. also verify namespace once

Comment: my products.php code is right I want to know  how to call that file in the form.xml that it

Comment: If you are not getting any error and stilll not getting product name then try to check if do you get product data from api repository in $product variable.

Comment: can u explain in brief what to do i cant get you

Comment: put this after your $product variable defination. 
echo "<pre/>";print_r($product->getData());die;

Comment: can u define the file path here

Comment: in the same file  and in prepareDataSource function.

Comment: cannot understand what you are telling

Comment: you can check product data after this line in your products.php file. `$product = $this->_ProductRepository->getById($item["entity_id"]);`

Comment: my products.php file is correct now i want to know how to cal it in form.xml